# Unity3D build code encryption

Tags: encryption, unity-game-engine, build, .net-assembly

I'd like to know whether it's possible to encrypt the compiled code in a Unity3D build in a way that de-compiling dlls won't give access to the legible source code to a potential hacker.

Cosmore pointed out in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663955/how-to-secure-unity3d-game-sources-from-cracking-on-android) that it's possible to

> 'encrypt the assembly dlls and modify the mono loader (libmono.so)'

My question is, has anybody done this? If so, how? And can it be done on Windows, Mac and Linux builds?

If this is not possible, is there another way?

Comment: any update on this? I know it is possible as a unity game is doing this but I myself would like to know this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But the hacker should be capable to run the build (ie. play the game)?

Then in **principle** it's not possible. While you can encrypt the code, you have to also provide the key, so people can play it (decrypt).

So you are just adding one more layer of obfuscation for hacker. A seasoned hacker will simply disassemble the dll loader and put a breakpoint to a place where the content is decrypted already, and dump that for further tinkering.

That said, not every hacker is a seasoned hacker, and few layers of (unexpected) obfuscation may turn them away. So practically some encryption/obfuscation is done by some people, even if in principle it's hopeless.

Comment: Maybe there's be a way to add the decryption into the monoloader so that it decrypts during runtime(?).. Not sure whether this is possible. The link in the question points to a post that suggests this or something similar to this.

Comment: Also, we're not looking to hack-proof it (which we know, is not possible).. We're just looking for a way to discourage potential hackers and to protect the source code.

Comment: Yes, that's the hint, to decrypt on the fly during load, and that's the place where I would put the breakpoint to extract the decrypted code. But I don't RE apps, and not every "script kid" can do that. But that's also true in your direction, not every one is capable to create such multi platform decrypt loader. That's the reason why there are different commercial packages promising to encrypt/obfuscate your code for different platforms. Did you check if some is available for Unity3D? (I'm not interested in Unity, so I don't follow SW around it)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. I'll do a bit of research on commercial encryption packages for Unity..